Motion-Based Screen Locking Script (Accelerometer) - Struggling with Parameter Tuning
I'm working on a PowerShell script to create a motion-activated screen lock for Windows tablets used in shag trucks (currently we use Microsoft Surfaces). The goal is to lock the screen when the vehicle is in motion and unlock it when stationary.
We're using the Windows.Devices.Sensors.Accelerometer to detect motion.
We're aware that PowerShell might not be the ideal solution for this task, and we're open to rebuilding it in C# / WinForms if necessary. However, we wanted to validate the concept and ensure it's possible before investing more time and resources -- just something that has been thrown in our direction and isn't something I've worked with much before so thought there might be someone a lot smarter than me here who can help us find the right path.
Our use case:

Windows tablets mounted in trucks -- they stop/start a lot and use the tablets for the software they need to track the trailers and such, but we don't want the tablet to be able to play videos or use facebook and stuff like that while in motion, so are trying to develop a custom lock screen that won't require them to interact with the keyboard/trackpad to unlock and won't false trigger when not actually in motion.

Screen should lock when the truck is moving to prevent driver interaction

Screen should unlock after the truck has been stationary for a set time


Current issues:

The script doesn't consistently lock the screen when motion is detected

When locked, it doesn't always unlock after the vehicle has stopped moving

Sometimes it locks/unlocks too easily with minor movements -- they have to carry it getting out of the truck sometimes or they might bump it when trying to type/use the trackpad, this just slows them down if it gets falsely locked because the accelerometer was triggered.


Might be something we have to live with since it seems hard to control with accelerometer data alone.
Here's our current PowerShell script:
# Load the necessary .NET assemblies
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Global variables
$script:lockScreenForm = $null
$script:countdownLabel = $null
$script:stationaryTimeLeft = 0
$script:isScreenLocked = $false
$script:timer = $null
$script:canUnlock = $false
$syncRoot = New-Object Object
$script:recentAccelerations = @()
$script:estimatedSpeed = 0
$movingAverageWindow = 5 # Reduced to be more responsive
$minimumLockSpeed = 0.5 # m/s, reduced to be more sensitive
$accelerationThreshold = 0.05 # m/s^2, reduced to be more sensitive
$stationaryTime = 3 # seconds before unlock is enabled

# Function to create the full-screen overlay form with a countdown timer
function New-LockScreen {
    try {
        Write-Log "Initializing lock screen form..."
        
        $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $form.Text = "Vehicle in Motion, Screen Locked"
        $form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::None
        $form.WindowState = [System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState]::Maximized
        $form.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Black
        $form.TopMost = $true

        $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $label.Text = "Vehicle in Motion, Screen Locked"
        $label.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White
        $label.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 48, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
        $label.AutoSize = $true
        $label.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Black
        $label.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
        $label.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter

        $script:countdownLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $script:countdownLabel.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White
        $script:countdownLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 24, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
        $script:countdownLabel.AutoSize = $false
        $script:countdownLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Black
        $script:countdownLabel.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Bottom
        $script:countdownLabel.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter
        $script:countdownLabel.Height = 100

        $form.Controls.Add($label)
        $form.Controls.Add($script:countdownLabel)

        $form.add_Shown({
            Write-Log "Form Shown event triggered."
            if ($form -ne $null) {
                $form.Activate()
                $form.Focus()
                $form.BringToFront()
            } else {
                Write-Log "Form is null in Shown event."
            }
        })

        $form.add_FormClosing({
            param($sender, $e)
            Write-Log "Form Closing event triggered."
            if ($e -ne $null) {
                $e.Cancel = $true
            } else {
                Write-Log "FormClosing event argument is null."
            }
        })

        $form.add_KeyDown({
            param($sender, $e)
            Write-Log "Key Down event triggered."
            Attempt-Unlock
        })

        $form.add_MouseMove({
            param($sender, $e)
            Write-Log "Mouse Move event triggered."
            Attempt-Unlock
        })

        return $form

    } catch {
        Write-Log "Failed to initialize lock screen form: $_"
    }
}

# Function to log messages to a file
function Write-Log {
    param (
        [string]$Message
    )
    $logDirectory = "C:\Logs"
    $logFilePath = Join-Path -Path $logDirectory -ChildPath "MotionControlLogger.txt"
    
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $logDirectory)) {
        New-Item -Path $logDirectory -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }
    
    $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    $logMessage = "$timestamp - $Message"
    Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value $logMessage
}

# Load the Accelerometer class
[Windows.Devices.Sensors.Accelerometer, Windows.Devices.Sensors, ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
$accelerometer = [Windows.Devices.Sensors.Accelerometer]::GetDefault()

if ($null -eq $accelerometer) {
    Write-Log "No accelerometer found on this device."
    return
}

# Function to lock the screen
function Invoke-Lock {
    try {
        Write-Log "Attempting to lock the screen."
        if (-not $script:lockScreenForm) {
            $script:lockScreenForm = New-LockScreen
            if ($script:lockScreenForm -ne $null) {
                $script:lockScreenForm.Show()
                $script:isScreenLocked = $true
                $script:stationaryTimeLeft = $stationaryTime
                $script:canUnlock = $false
                Write-Log "Screen locked."
            } else {
                Write-Log "Failed to create lock screen form."
            }
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Log "Failed to lock the screen: $_"
    }
}

# Function to unlock the screen
function Invoke-Unlock {
    try {
        Write-Log "Attempting to unlock the screen."
        if ($null -ne $script:lockScreenForm) {
            $script:lockScreenForm.Hide()
            $script:lockScreenForm.Close()
            $script:lockScreenForm.Dispose()
            $script:lockScreenForm = $null
            $script:isScreenLocked = $false
            $script:stationaryTimeLeft = $stationaryTime
            $script:canUnlock = $false
            Write-Log "Screen unlocked."
            [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Log "Failed to unlock the screen: $_"
    }
}

# Function to attempt unlocking
function Attempt-Unlock {
    Write-Log "Attempt-Unlock called. Can Unlock: $script:canUnlock"
    if ($script:canUnlock) {
        Write-Log "Calling Invoke-Unlock"
        Invoke-Unlock
    }
}

# Function to handle accelerometer data and estimate speed
function Update-MotionState {
    param (
        [double]$AccelX,
        [double]$AccelY,
        [double]$AccelZ,
        [double]$TimeDelta
    )

    # Calculate vector magnitude
    $magnitude = [Math]::Sqrt($AccelX * $AccelX + $AccelY * $AccelY + $AccelZ * $AccelZ)

    # Apply low-pass filter (simple exponential smoothing)
    $alpha = 0.3 # Increased smoothing factor for faster response
    $script:smoothedMagnitude = if ($null -eq $script:smoothedMagnitude) { $magnitude } else { $alpha * $magnitude + (1 - $alpha) * $script:smoothedMagnitude }

    # Update recent accelerations list
    $script:recentAccelerations += $script:smoothedMagnitude
    if ($script:recentAccelerations.Count -gt $movingAverageWindow) {
        $script:recentAccelerations = $script:recentAccelerations[-$movingAverageWindow..-1]
    }

    # Calculate moving average
    $movingAverage = ($script:recentAccelerations | Measure-Object -Average).Average

    # Estimate speed (very rough approximation)
    $accelerationDelta = $movingAverage - 1 # Subtract 1 to account for gravity
    $script:estimatedSpeed += $accelerationDelta * $TimeDelta
    $script:estimatedSpeed = [Math]::Max(0, $script:estimatedSpeed) # Ensure speed is not negative

    $isMoving = ($script:estimatedSpeed -gt $minimumLockSpeed) -or ([Math]::Abs($accelerationDelta) -gt $accelerationThreshold)

    Write-Log "Debug: Magnitude=$magnitude, Smoothed=$script:smoothedMagnitude, MovingAvg=$movingAverage, EstSpeed=$script:estimatedSpeed, AccelDelta=$accelerationDelta, IsMoving=$isMoving"

    if ($isMoving) {
        if (-not $script:isScreenLocked) {
            Write-Log "Vehicle motion detected! Locking the screen..."
            Invoke-Lock
        } else {
            Write-Log "Vehicle in motion. Resetting countdown..."
            [System.Threading.Monitor]::Enter($syncRoot)
            try {
                $script:stationaryTimeLeft = $stationaryTime
                $script:canUnlock = $false
            } finally {
                [System.Threading.Monitor]::Exit($syncRoot)
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ($script:isScreenLocked) {
            [System.Threading.Monitor]::Enter($syncRoot)
            try {
                if ($script:stationaryTimeLeft -gt 0) {
                    $script:stationaryTimeLeft--
                    if ($null -ne $script:countdownLabel) {
                        $script:countdownLabel.Text = "Time until unlock enabled: $script:stationaryTimeLeft seconds"
                    } else {
                        Write-Log "countdownLabel is null."
                    }
                } elseif (-not $script:canUnlock) {
                    $script:canUnlock = $true
                    if ($null -ne $script:countdownLabel) {
                        $script:countdownLabel.Text = "Unlock enabled. Move mouse or press any key to unlock."
                    } else {
                        Write-Log "countdownLabel is null."
                    }
                    Write-Log "Countdown completed. Unlock enabled."
                }
            } finally {
                [System.Threading.Monitor]::Exit($syncRoot)
            }
        }
    }

    Write-Log "State: Speed=$script:estimatedSpeed, StationaryTime=$script:stationaryTimeLeft, Locked=$script:isScreenLocked, CanUnlock=$script:canUnlock"
}

# Main script execution
try {
    $script:timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    $script:timer.Interval = 100 # Reduced to 100ms for more frequent sampling
    $script:lastReadingTime = $null

    $script:timer.add_Tick({
        try {
            if ($null -ne $accelerometer) {
                $reading = $accelerometer.GetCurrentReading()

                if ($null -eq $reading) {
                    Write-Log "Failed to get reading from accelerometer"
                    return
                }

                $currentTime = Get-Date
                $timeDelta = if ($script:lastReadingTime -ne $null) { ($currentTime - $script:lastReadingTime).TotalSeconds } else { 0.1 }
                $script:lastReadingTime = $currentTime

                $accelX = [double]$reading.AccelerationX
                $accelY = [double]$reading.AccelerationY
                $accelZ = [double]$reading.AccelerationZ
                Update-MotionState -AccelX $accelX -AccelY $accelY -AccelZ $accelZ -TimeDelta $timeDelta
            } else {
                Write-Log "Accelerometer is null"
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Log "An error occurred in timer tick: $_"
            Write-Log "Detailed exception: $($_ | Out-String)"
        }
    })

    $script:timer.Start()
    Write-Log "Timer started"

    # Create and show an invisible form to keep the script running
    $invisibleForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $invisibleForm.WindowState = [System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState]::Minimized
    $invisibleForm.ShowInTaskbar = $false
    $invisibleForm.add_Load({ $invisibleForm.Hide() })

    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($invisibleForm)
} finally {
    Write-Log "Script execution ending."
    if ($null -ne $script:lockScreenForm) {
        Write-Log "Closing lockScreenForm."
        $script:lockScreenForm.Close()
        $script:lockScreenForm.Dispose()
    }
    if ($null -ne $script:timer) {
        Write-Log "Stopping timer."
        $script:timer.Stop()
        $script:timer.Dispose()
    }
    Write-Log "Script execution ended."
}

We've tried adjusting various parameters like:

$movingAverageWindow
$minimumLockSpeed
$accelerationThreshold
$stationaryTime

But we haven't found the right combination to make it work reliably.

We adjusted the $movingAverageWindow (5-20 samples) expecting smoother motion detection.
We modified $minimumLockSpeed (0.5-2 m/s) and $accelerationThreshold (0.05-0.1 m/s^2), expecting to find a sweet spot for detecting vehicle motion while ignoring minor movements.
We altered $stationaryTime (3-5 seconds) to balance quick unlocking with avoiding premature unlocks.
We expected these adjustments would result in:
Consistent screen locking when the vehicle starts moving.
Screen remaining locked during constant-speed motion.
Screen unlocking reliably after the vehicle stops for the set time.
However, the actual results were inconsistent:
Sometimes the screen wouldn't lock during obvious motion.
Other times it would lock/unlock too easily with minor movements.
Occasionally, it wouldn't unlock even after the vehicle had been stationary for an extended period.
We're struggling to find the right combination of parameters that works reliably across different motion scenarios.
Questions for those who might have some experience or a better approach!

Are there any obvious issues with our current approach or implementation that we're missing?
Can you suggest improvements to make the motion detection more reliable?
Would switching to C# / WinForms provide significant benefits for this type of application? Have done some research but haven't found a good implementation we could try to mirror
Are there any alternative approaches or libraries we should consider for more accurate motion detection on Windows tablets?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The device should be locked down ("kiosk mode"); and only show the app / options that are relevant; moving or not. And all actions on the device logged.

That's a pretty good idea that didn't occur to me. Not sure if we can configure Kiosk mode to run the applications we need to and only those, but it would potentially meet our use case since it's unlikely that they would want to use the software while moving -- other than potentially trying to get ahead and work on the surface while they are driving.

Where is code getting locked?   Is movement becoming negative?   You are subtracting one from moving average and when less than 1 the number will become negative.   Just changing parameters without understanding the reason for the locking is not going to solve issue.  Best way of debugging issue like this is to create a log file and save debug data into the log so you can see what is happening in real time.

@jdweng yeah it would make sense to be more methodical in our approach. I'm going to dig more into the logging -- we do have logs but the way the accelerometer data is coming in needs to be analyzed and seeing it in real time will be a big help -- there's actually a program called Sensor Explorer that graphs it as well.

You can add  a time with each log entry.

I'm more concerned to find out why code is getting locked which shouldn't need real time analysis.

Your code seems tightly coupled to the physical accelerometer device. You might want to wrap that so you can create a separate mock accelerometer for regression testing any changes you make - e.g. does a canned sequence of data points still correctly trigger your “lock” and “unlock” events - so you can test changes automatically against multiple scenarios without needing to physically wave a laptop around in the air. That’s not impossible in Powershell, but there’s probably better support and tooling in C#…

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/customize/kiosk-mode

Thanks for the responses! Just getting back around to this today but I'm going to add more robust logging and look into the mock accelerometer for regression testing as suggested by @mclayton -- it is getting a bit annoying to wave the device around or walk around to test it and I think we need to capture more movement data to give us a better idea of the parameters and what is triggering lock/unlock, etc.
Kiosk mode might be a good alternative if I can't figure something else out or as a temporary solution until we can reevaluate. They want a bunch of other features eventually.

Having researched this a bit, it's worth noting that the accelerometer readings have a timestamp of their own - you should probably use that rather than Get-Date as the reading may be subject to lag before it's received, which could affect your calculations. Instead of $currentTime = Get-Date you should do something like $readingTimestamp = [datetimeoffset]$reading.Timestamp and base your calculations off that. See the Properties section of  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.sensors.accelerometerreading?view=winrt-26100#properties

@mclayton thank you! I had overlooked that entirely but that is a good point and helpful reference.
